# DjangoAdmin: How to keep the '＋✎ ✕' buttons for a Foreign Key on when using `AutocompleteSelect` widget

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I'm using the `AutocompleteSelect` widget for a ForeignKey field. To do this, I override the default Admin Form using the `ModelForm` class like this:

```
class ContainerModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    some_fk = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=SomeModel.objects.all(),
        widget=AutocompleteSelect(ContainerModel.some_fk.field.remote_field, admin.site)
    )
```

However, by using this widget I lose the `＋ ✎ ✕` buttons that are available on the Django Admin interface for a Foreign Key field by default.

[image]

What will be a good way to use `AutoCompleteSelect` widget but also keeping these Add/Edit/Delete buttons besides the foreign key field on the Admin UI?

Answer (score 1):

Django seems to wrap widgets for `ForeignKey` and `ManyToManyField` from model regardless of the form field type / widget used.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/920448539631b52dcee53bd32a880abbc9de18bd/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L144-L175

Are you sure `some_fk` is an actual field in the model?

Even if it's not, you can probably achieve something similar by wrapping it the same way.